# Using v120 Platform Toolset in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) in Windows 10. I have one Solution consisting of several projects. One of these projects **has to** be built with platform toolset Visual Studio 2013(v120). Unfortunately, It's not installed on my machine. I know how to change platform toolset for projects or retarget Solution but I don't want to do this. I want to install Visual Studio 2013 platform toolset (v120) for Visual Studion 2015. The only way that I found so far is to install the whole Visual Studio 2013 besides 2015 version which is not a good solution.

I have tried different solution for this problem such as installing v120 build tools separately and [Look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801072/the-builds-tools-for-v120-platform-toolset-v120-cannot-be-found). But it did not work for me. 
Any solution except installing Visual Studio 2013 would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install the VS2013 toolset from your VS2015 installer without installing Visual Studio 2013.

From the 2015 installer, select "*Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools*" and "*Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015*":

[image: Visual Studio 2015 installer]

After the installation has completed, you will find the platform Toolset below:

[image: Installed toolsets in VS2015]

You should now be able to build your project with the platform toolset for Visual Studio 2013 (v120).

Comment: Now this is interesting. Is there similar functionality in VS2017 as well? E.g. are there options to install v120 and/or v140 toolsets?

Comment: @stijn, yes, there is option VC++ 2015.3 v140 Toolset(x86,x64) on the Visual Studio Installer on Visual Studio 2017 RTM. But only v140 can be selected, have no v120.

Comment: Is there a way to get v120 on visual studio 2017 besides having to install VS 2013?

Comment: i know, one year later but did you find a solution @cjsimon ?

Comment: VS 2015 Community edition doesn't seem to have the installer. Workaround is:<br/><br/>
Navigate to Control Panel<br/>
Go to Programs<br/>
Click on Programs and Features<br/>
Find Microsoft Visual Studio in the list of programs<br/>
Right click on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015<br/>
Select Change<br/>
Select Modify<br/>
Choose the packages you want<br/>
Select Next<br/>

Comment: Not possible on Windows 7, or at least I don't see the second install option :(