# Windows 8.1 SDK doesn't find math.h

Tags: windows, sdk, visual-studio-2017, msvcrt, crt

Due to problems with Windows 10 SDK in MSVC 2017 I'm trying the Windows 8.1 SDK, but I cannot compile anything, because there is no CRT - it doesn't find math.h (and probably others). What is happening exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install the Platform Toolset from an earlier version of Visual Studio.  Consider using Visual Studio 2013 which includes the Windows 8.1 SDK, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42687137/3842894), though I have not tested it.

Generally speaking, it seems Microsoft does not support installing platform toolsets independently of installing Visual Studio.  And it seems that installing older Visual Studio versions can lead to problems, when a newer version is already installed.  The last time I attempted this, the newer version began producing build errors afterwards.

It seems to be a common source of frustration - missing or improperly installed Platform Toolsets.  And there does not appear to be a good generalized answer to the problem.  Ideally, Microsoft would provide all versions of toolset installers (without full Visual Studio install) to their MSDN subscribers.

Comment: Thanks, that might be it. In the meantime I installed VC2013 and after that VC2017 and now it is ok. It's not exactly ideal thing MS did :)