# How can I install and use build tools v120 (2013) on Visual Studio 2015 from a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I need to build several C++ projects (originally developed with VS 2013) that require v120 build tools. I can only use VS2015 (due to licensing and other corporate formalities I cannot install VS2013).

As per multiple similar SO questions, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669153/using-v120-platform-toolset-in-visual-studio-2015) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914828/microsoft-build-tools-2013-missing-v120-directory/48851425), it appears my only options are to:

- Install VS2013 - (NOT POSSIBLE)
- Use VS2015 installer to install *Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1* - also NOT POSSIBLE since the machine I am using is running Windows 7 and *Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1* just doesn't appear in the installer.
- Retarget the projects to build using v140 - again NOT POSSIBLE as this will effectively render the projects unusable by my colleagues who also work with these projects.

Isn't there any standalone installer that I can use to install those build tools, or any other option I can try?

Comment: Alternative solution: make all your projects use $(DefaultPlatformToolset) as toolset instead of hardcoding the toolset to v140 etc. (use a text editor to change the PlatformToolset property in the project files). While undocumented, that property exists since at least VS2012, and using it will make VS not ask you to upgrade and just use whatever version the build is started with, both in VS and commandline builds. Note this does mean if you don't have VS2013 you still cannot build with it, but at least your colleagues won't have problems...

Comment: ... unless you use features which are not supported in VS2013, that is. E.g. no C++14 etc.

Comment: I will try and see if it complicates things for my colleagues, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't there any standalone installer that I can use to install those build tools, or any other option I can try?

I am afraid there is no such standalone installer that you can use to install the build tools v120 on the windows 7. Just as you found, the option `Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools` could not be installed on the windows 7.

But, there is a workaround to resolve this issue, install the **Visual Studio 2013 express** instead of Visual Studio 2013.

You can download it [here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015).

[image]

Visual Studio 2013 express will resolve your licensing restriction, but I am not sure if it match your corporate formalities. If not, I think you can consider stijn`s suggestion "*use $(DefaultPlatformToolset) as toolset instead of hardcoding the toolset to v140*"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! At least I know I don't really have any option but to install VS 2013. One formality is that we're not allowed to install anything from external sources, such as Microsoft / MSDN. Every piece of software we have is installed through our company's own software manager solution and, supposedly, the apps are screened and, if necessary, modified so that they comply with our policies. Unfortunately, VS 2013 express is not available on the list.